# Using spring Web Client hit https rest service

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, ssl-certificate, spring-webclient

I have got two `.cer` file from client now my goal is to hit client api using https rather than http using spring webclient . As I am new to spring webclient not getting clue what to do

I have imported both .cer in keystore using below command

```
keytool -import -file "C:\Users\ankur\Download\Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority-G2.cer" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass "changeit"

keytool -import -file "C:\Users\ankur\Download\certificate\Entrust_Certification_Authority-L1K.cer" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass "changeit
```

I have written below to code in order to hit the api programatically from webclient

```
@Bean

       public WebClient createWebClient() throws SSLException {

             SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder

                           .forClient()

                           .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)

                           .build();          

             HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient

                           .create()

                           .secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext));

                    ClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);

             return WebClient.builder()

                           .clientConnector(connector).build();

       }



application.yml
    rest:
      endpoint:https://someexample.com/xyz
```

I have no idea what to do with .cer file where to store these .cer file do we need to include in resource folder of spring boot any example or link would be helpful thanks

Comment: Look here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate

Answer (score 0):

below is the one of the approach with that you can configure ssl certs to `webclient`
 

**Step 1:** Copy your required certs to your `resources` folder
 
let's take an example as `config/Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority-G2.cer`

**Step 2:** Create a property to configure the location of your certs as below in one of your configuration class

```
  @Value("${entrust.ssl.cert.path:config/Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority-G2.cer}")
  private String entrustSslCertFilePath;
```

**Step 3:** Load these certs while creating `SslContext`

```
SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
            .trustManager(new ClassPathResource(entrustSslCertFilePath).getInputStream())
            .build();
```

Note: Above metioned i have used with `pem` file which worked properly, give a try and if required feel free to convert `cer` to `pem` file and [sslshopper](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html) will be very helpful for validating and converting ssl certs

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the answer i have two certificate do i need to put these two certificate in resource folder or both can be converted in one pem file

Comment: looks like both certs are for Entrust , so i think it's possible to convert both into one pem file but i am not sure, please test it out different combinations , if above approach solves your problem please accept it, so that it will helpful others